# In my mediaquery : some css properties work, other don't

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I've made a mediaquery and, strangely, some of the new css properties work and other don't...

working : .ctas and .footer-content

When I use the chrome inspector, I doesn't even detects the mediaquery for the classes not working...

You can see the page I'm working on here : http://sopureinthecity.fr/test/

```
@media screen and (max-width:570px) {

    .ctas {
        width: 270px;
    }

    .footer-content {
        padding-top: 20px;  
    }

    .img-reponsive {
  margin-top: 40px;   
    }


    .main-title {
        top: 30%;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 18px;
    }


    .modal-btn {
        top: 48%;  
    }

}
```

What did I do wrong ?

Thanks in advance !

EDIT, so everything works in the browser, but my .large-header is all bugged when I visit the website on my phone !

The responsive of the .large-header only works on the desktop (with a phone screen size)

Comment: as I see .main-title works as well https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/32989095/screenshots/so-media-quey.JPG and I assume that all of them work fine

Comment: ok, main-title works well indeed, but not the modal button and the img-responsive :s

Comment: in the img-responsive you have a typo.

Answer (score 3):

You have typos in your css selectors when compared to the site you have linked:

.img-reponsive vs .img-responsive

.modal-btn vs .modalbtn

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is wrong with the media query. The issue is a typo:

```
.modal-btn {
```

should be

```
.modalbtn {
```

As the CSS class used in your page is `modalbtn`.